# Access Hive table from HDinsight cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am using pyspark to access hive inside my HDinsight cluster. When i go and query hive it shows me all the databases but when i query from spark it just shows default database.

I believe it just go and query spark catalog by default.

The workaround i found was i should use Hive warehouse connector to connect to hive from spark.

Is there any other way to do it?

**Code**

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hn0-mytestua.abc.dxbx.internal.cloudapp.net:9083") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", '/hive/warehouse/external') \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sql("show databases").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify hive related configuration in spark code then you can simply copy hive-site.xml file from $HIVE_HOME/conf foder to $SPARK_HOME/conf folder.

If it's not possible to do file copy then you can use below configurations while creating `SparkSession` or while launching spark jobs to connect to hive.

```
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars = $HIVE_HOME/lib/* // No need to specify this if it's already in CLASSPATH
spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris = thrift://<host>:9083
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version= <hive version>
```

No need to specify metastore version if your hive version matches with default version specified here in [documenation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html).

Azure HDInsight provides [HWC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/interactive-query/apache-hive-warehouse-connector) connector to integrate hive with spark.

Comment: i don't  have access to files there are just properties in ambari

Comment: Okay, then you can go ahead with programmatic approach only.

Comment: and what is that?

Comment: but this is not working, it is by default pointing to spark catalog, how to change it?

Comment: Updated the answer, check with those configurations.

Comment: i have added .config("spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars" , '$HIVE_HOME/lib/*' ) \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", '/hive/warehouse/external')  in configs,it still doesn't show up hive tables.

Comment: You are using spark-submit command and launching your spark app right?

Comment: btw what's hive and spark versions?

Comment: Hive 3.1.0.4.1.5.19, spark 2.4.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236327/discussion-between-mohana-b-c-and-user7422128).